# How to use react router navigation links from separate component file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have header component which has navigation in a separate .js file.

```
<Router>
  <h1>AshoKart</h1>
    <div className="cart">
      <span>Cart (0 items)</span>
      <Link to='/checkout'>Checkout</Link>
    </div>
    <br />
    <nav>
      <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
      <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
    </nav>
 </Router>
```

I have Route path details in App.js file.

```
<Router>   
  <Route path="/" exact>      
    <Home />
  </Route> 
  <Route path="/about">      
    <About />
  </Route> 
  <Route path="/checkout">      
    <Checkout />
  </Route> 
</Router>
```

When I click the links, it is not navigating. But if I add the navigation links in app.js file it is working fine. Can you please tell me how to make the navigation links work from separate file?

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of `<Router>` in the component file. Your components are already embedded inside the one in the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<router/>` in the Header component same as the below code. It should navigate now.

```
<div>
                          <h1>AshoKart</h1>
                        <div className="cart">
                            <span>Cart (0 items)</span>
                                <Link to='/checkout'>Checkout</Link>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <nav>
                                <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                                <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
                        </nav>
    </div>
```